# Unknown Error when trying to work with official Ktor SSE-Sample

Tags: kotlin, http, server-sent-events, ktor

im currently trying to implement Server-Side Events for my Ktor-Api. I tried getting the official sse-sample to work i found on https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples/tree/1.3.0/other/sse but when i run the server and call the sse-http-request the server throws following Errors:

```
ERROR ktor.application - Unhandled exception caught for CoroutineName(call-handler)
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException.<init>(ReflectiveOperationException.java:89)
    at java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(InvocationTargetException.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:66)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:60)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:72)
```

Here is the code sample:

```
fun main() {
    
        embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) { // this: Application ->
    
            val channel = produce { // this: ProducerScope<SseEvent> ->
                var n = 0
                while (true) {
                    send(SseEvent("demo$n"))
                    delay(1000)
                    n++
                }
            }.broadcast()
            
            routing {
    
                get("/sse") {
                    val events = channel.openSubscription()
                    try {
                        call.respondSse(events)
                    } finally {
                        events.cancel()
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }.start(wait = true)
    }
    
    data class SseEvent(val data: String, val event: String? = null, val id: String? = null)
    
    suspend fun ApplicationCall.respondSse(events: ReceiveChannel<SseEvent>) {
        response.cacheControl(CacheControl.NoCache(null))
        respondTextWriter(contentType = ContentType.Text.EventStream) {
            for (event in events) {
                if (event.id != null) {
                    write("id: ${event.id}\n")
                }
                if (event.event != null) {
                    write("event: ${event.event}\n")
                }
                for (dataLine in event.data.lines()) {
                    write("data: $dataLine\n")
                }
                write("\n")
                flush()
            }
        }
    }
```

Im pretty sure the error comes from the flush command, since i once tried sse using a different approach(without flush) and it kinda worked but i cant follow that approach for different reasons.

Comment: The sample you mention is outdated. Please see the one https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples/tree/main/sse that is up-to-date.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman Hey, it led to the same Error, however i just found the problem. Gonna make an Answer shortly